# react smart/dumb component pattern for changing data

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm starting to implement the smart/dumb component pattern where the "dumb" component knows nothing about it's environment and receives all of it's data through props. What do you do when the dumb component has to submit or change data? How can it communicate with the outside world and still be "dumb"?

Here's my basic example I'm using to figure this pattern out. If I were to add and `onClick` event to the `MyTask` component that updated a counter in the DB, what would handle that event?

```
// components/MyList.jsx

import React from 'react';

export default class MyList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.listName}</h3>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
                        <MyTask key={task.id} task={task} />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
MyList.propTypes = {
    listName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    tasks: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}



export class MyTask extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.task.text}</li>
        );
    }
}
MyTask.propTypes = {
    task: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

and the app:

```
// app.jsx

import React from 'react';
import MyList from './components/MyList.jsx'


export class TaskApp extends React.Component {

    getList() {
        return('Today Stuff');
    }

    getTasks() {
        return([
            {id: 1, text: 'foo'},
            {id: 2, text: 'diggity'},
            {id: 3, text: 'boo'},
            {id: 4, text: 'bop'}
        ]);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyList listName={this.getList()} tasks={this.getTasks()} />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you can handle this by passing function references from your 'smart' components down to your 'dumb' components. The dumb component then isn't responsible for implementing any of the logic associated with the function, just telling the smart component 'I've been clicked'.

In this case inside of your TaskApp class in app.jsx you could have your click handler:

```
//app.jsx
...
handleClick() {
  // Update the DB counter by 1
}
...
render () {}
```

Then pass handleClick through your components as a prop:

```
<MyList listName={this.getList()} tasks={this.getTasks()} handleClick={this.handleClick} />

<MyTask key={task.id} task={task} handleClick={this.props.handleClick} />
```

And execute it in the MyTask component when a list element is clicked:

```
<li onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.task.text}</li>
```

Keep in mind that if the handleClick() function is making use of 'this' at all, you'll need to .bind(this) on your function reference when you pass it down (or bind it in the constructor / use ES6 fat arrow functions).

**EDIT**: For examples of the other ways to bind 'this', you could in the constructor of your class assign the bound function to your this.handleClick reference, so:

```
export default class TaskApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

...
...
}
```

Which allows you to use this.handleClick the way you would normally expect.

Or you could use ES6 fat arrow functions, which preserve the context of 'this' when they are called:

```
<MyList 
  listName={this.getList()} 
  tasks={this.getTasks()} 
  handleClick={() => this.handleClick} />
```

Comment: Accepted answer for being a bit more verbose in the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an example of the two different bindings of `this` please? This would be a very thorough answer with that addition.

Comment: Added a few extra examples of binding context to the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that TaskApp is the smart component and  MyList is the dumb component, it should be something like

Smart Component

```
// app.jsx

import React from 'react';
import MyList from './components/MyList.jsx'


export class TaskApp extends React.Component {

    getList() {
        return('Today Stuff');
    }

    getTasks() {
        return([
            {id: 1, text: 'foo'},
            {id: 2, text: 'diggity'},
            {id: 3, text: 'boo'},
            {id: 4, text: 'bop'}
        ]);
    }
    handleClick(task){
      // update the db here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyList listName={this.getList()} tasks={this.getTasks()} 
                onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Dumb Component

```
// components/MyList.jsx

import React from 'react';

export default class MyList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.listName}</h3>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
                        <MyTask onClick={() => this.props.onClick(task)}
                             key={task.id} task={task} />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
MyList.propTypes = {
    listName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    tasks: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}



export class MyTask extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.task.text}</li>
        );
    }
}
MyTask.propTypes = {
    task: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the event handler callback as a prop to `MyTask`:

```
<MyTask onClick={this.handleTaskClick.bind(this)} ... />
```

And then use it in MyTask:

```
<li onClick={this.props.onClick}>...</li>
```

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#callbacks-as-props

Comment: Since there were three answers very similar to each other within a few minutes of posting, this seems seems to be the popular method. Thank you!